# Etymologie et origines de "bof"

Tags: étymologie, onomatopées

J'aurais souhaité savoir quelles sont les origines de l'onomatopée "bof", utilisée pour décrire quelque chose de médiocre, de peu plaisant.

En effet, je n'ai trouvé aucune source mentionnant l'étymologie de ce mot. À partir de quand a-t-il été utilisé ? Quels sont les plus anciens textes qui en font mention ?

Merci d'avance de vos éclaircissements!

Comment: Très bonne question. Bravo !

Comment: Je suis totalement d’accord avec @Watson, il y a confusion. Mais c’est très intéressant de connaître l’étymologie de « beauf »!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après [languefrancaise.net](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/42464), la plus ancienne référence de *bof* avec cette acception date de 1967 *[L'argot chez les mineurs délinquants](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Source/4076)*

Pour ce qui est de l'étymologie, il s'agit d'une onomatopée reproduisant le bruit de l'air de joues gonflées sortant par les lèvres se desserrant, similaire à *pfft* qui existe aussi en anglais.

Grevisse confirme le caractère onomatopéique de *bof* (LBU, 16e éd., 2016, p231).

Answer (score 1):

Voici ce que j'ai trouvé.

> https://www.thelocal.fr/20181102/french-word-of-the-day-bof
>
> It's a French classic you need to know. Why do I need to know bof?
>
> If you're feeling demotivated, indifferent, or want to engage in the
>   traditional French pastime of avoiding being positive (being honest)
>   about things, this is a need to know word.
>
> Plus it’s a French classic, right up there with pfff, exaggerated
>   shrugging and oh la la.
>
> **What does it mean?**
>
> Historically it’s thought that this word might be linked to the
>   **acronym of Bœuf, Œuf, Fromage**. All three foods were rationed during
>   the German war-time occupation in France and **black marketeers** became
>   known as **BOFs**. Overtime bof  has lost this unscrupulous association
>   and come to mean something quite different.
>
> Bof is a spoken interjection that translates more as a feeling of
>   disinterest or mild unhappiness than an actual word.
>
> It’s nearly always used as an indifferent or slightly negative
>   response to a question, for example, - Que penses-tu de ce film? –
>   Bof. Pas terrible. (What did you think of the film? – Whatever. It
>   wasn’t terrible.)
>
> Similarly bof could also be the response to ‘Don’t you think the film
>   is great?’ (Tu trouves pas que ce film est génial?) or ‘Do you want to
>   go to the cinema? (Ca te dit d'aller au cinéma?), meaning an apathetic
>   ‘not really’ in both cases.
>
> It could also be a slightly depressing reply to ça va? meaning ‘not
>   great’, ‘ok’, or ‘meh’.
>
> Considering that a normal reply would be ‘fine’ or ‘good thanks’
>   (bien, merci) saying you are just ‘alright’, ‘ok’ or bof actually
>   implies that you feeling a bit miserable.
>
> Finally, if you’re going to use this classic French sound you might as
>   well go the whole hog and Frenchify your gestures too; bof is often
>   said with an indifferent expression and dismissive shrug of the
>   shoulders.
>
> How can I use bof?
>
> - Est-ce que tu as faim? - Bof...
> - Are you hungry? – Not really…
> - Tu t-amuses bien? – Bof.
> - Are you having a good time? – Meh.

Un article français plus court affirme aussi cette étymologie :

> https://www.gqmagazine.fr/mode/style-academie/articles/quest-ce-qui-differencie-le-bof-du-beauf-/23915
>
> L’expression, qui n’est pas une bête contraction de “beau-frère”,
>   révèle un acronyme plus recherché : Beurre Œufs Fromage. Au temps de
>   la Seconde Guerre mondiale, les restrictions alimentaires font le lit
>   du marché noir. Sous l’enseigne “Beurre Œufs Fromage”, les épiciers
>   les moins scrupuleux se font du blé sur le dos des pauvres. L’insulte
>   désigne depuis lors une personne sans éthique ni scrupule.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Ceci dit, il me semble qu'il y a confusion avec le "beauf" désignant (familièrement) "beau-frère". En effet, [cette page](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beauf) fait précisément le lien (que j'ignorais !) avec _Beurre/Œuf/Fromage_. Il n'est pas clair ce qu'il en est de l'interjection "bof". Selon votre réponse, cette interjection ne peut pas apparaître dans des écrits datant d'avant la seconde guerre mondiale ; cela mérite vérification.